# Unsure how to represent a 3D packing problem for a NN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm still figuring out how to structure my problem statement. For now, it's the following:

There is a 3D room with a fixed size. You are given 3 shapes composed of unit blocks. Each shape is associated with a value. You must fill the room using these shapes while trying to maximize the total value. You can reuse a shape as many times as you wish.

I think my problem is a blend between a 3D packing and a knapsack problem. I would like to solve it using a feed forward NN because I think it would be fun. I doubt NNs are the most efficient solution.

I need some help figuring out how to represent the network's input and output. I know the representations should be of a fixed size (I'd like to avoid recurrent networks) and ideally would prevent impossible states. But I'm not sure what else I should consider.

Perhaps if I constrain the volume of the shapes to a fixed number of unit blocks, I could represent both the input and the output using a one-hot encoding?

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: This does not make sense to me as a neural network problem (or logistic regression, or SVM, or random forest, etc).

Comment: Could you expand on what difficulties I might encounter? I imagine trowing a NN to everything might not be a great idea but I'm just using it as a learning exercise